# Issue with type name demangling

Tags: c++, c++11, typeinfo

I was creating a template class that transforms a type into a string describing it, eg `typeinfo<int(*)()>::name()` returns the string `"int(*)()"` (up to whitespace). Initially I had tons of special cases to work around the fact that `typeid(...).name()` strips off reference qualifiers and top-level cv-qualifiers, but then I remembered that passing a type as a template parameter will preserve these. So, using the ABI header, I ended up with something like this:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <cxxabi.h>

using namespace std;

string demangle(const char* mangledName) {
    int status;
    char* result = abi::__cxa_demangle(mangledName, nullptr, nullptr, &status);
    switch(status) {
    case -1:
        cerr << "Out of memory!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    case -2:
        return mangledName;
    case -3: // Should never happen, but just in case?
        return mangledName;
    }
    string name = result;
    free(result);
    return name;
}

template<typename T> struct preserve_qualifiers {};

template<typename T> class typeinfo {
    using wrap = preserve_qualifiers<T>;
public:
    static const string name() {
        string name = demangle(typeid(wrap).name());
        int i = name.find_first_of('<');
        if(i == string::npos) return name;
        int j = name.length() - i - 2;
        return name.substr(i + 1, j);
    }
};

#define TypeOut(...) cout \
    << "Type " #__VA_ARGS__ ": " << endl \
    << "  Mangled: " << typeid(__VA_ARGS__).name() << endl \
    << "  Demangled: " << demangle(typeid(__VA_ARGS__).name()) << endl \
    << "  typeinfo<>: " << typeinfo<__VA_ARGS__>::name() << endl
class A {};
template<typename T> class F {};
template<int T> class G {};
template<template<typename> class T> class H {};
template<template<int> class T> class I {};
template<typename... T> class J {};
template<int... T> class K {};
template<template<typename> class... T> class L {};
template<template<int> class... T> class M {};
template<template<typename> class... T> class N {};
template<template<template<typename> class...> class... T> class O {};
struct bits {int i : 4, j : 2;};
template<typename T, int n> struct bits2 {T val : n;};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TypeOut(void(*volatile)(void(*const)()));
    TypeOut(int (A::*)());
    TypeOut(int (A::*)()const);
    TypeOut(int (A::*const)());
#ifdef __clang__
    TypeOut(int (A::*)()&);
    TypeOut(int (A::*)()&&);
#endif
    TypeOut(F<int>);
    TypeOut(G<3>);
    TypeOut(H<F>);
    TypeOut(I<G>);
    TypeOut(J<int>);
    TypeOut(K<3>);
    TypeOut(L<F>);
    TypeOut(M<G>);
    TypeOut(N<F,F,F>);
    TypeOut(O<N,N>);
}
```

This compiles and works (nearly) perfectly in GCC (4.8). However, GCC doesn't support the ref-qualifiers on member functions, so tried it in Clang as well (3.2) to see if it would work. It doesn't. It compiles fine, and runs without issue, but most of the template names are not demangled, and nor are the ref-qualified member functions.

[Here](http://ideone.com/05yxL) is the GCC output from ideone (the code was tweaked slightly since ideone's version of GCC doesn't support nullptr or alias declarations). Notice the missing const qualifier in the function parameter. That's the only thing that didn't work as I'd hoped in GCC. It's the same in Clang, too, which I suppose isn't especially surprising. (What's surprising is that it's missing at all, not that GCC and Clang are consistent on it.)

Unfortunately, when compiling and running with Clang, the variadic templated classes could not be demangled. For example, J was mangled to `1JIJiEE` instead of the `1JIIiEE` that GCC chose.

Selected output from clang (showing only the ones that didn't work)

```
Type int (A::*)()&: 
  Mangled: M1AFivRE
  Demangled: M1AFivRE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersIM1AFivREE
Type int (A::*)()&&: 
  Mangled: M1AFivOE
  Demangled: M1AFivOE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersIM1AFivOEE
Type J<int>: 
  Mangled: 1JIJiEE
  Demangled: 1JIJiEE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersI1JIJiEEE
Type K<3>: 
  Mangled: 1KIJLi3EEE
  Demangled: 1KIJLi3EEE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersI1KIJLi3EEEE
Type L<F>: 
  Mangled: 1LIJ1FEE
  Demangled: 1LIJ1FEE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersI1LIJ1FEEE
Type M<G>: 
  Mangled: 1MIJ1GEE
  Demangled: 1MIJ1GEE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersI1MIJ1GEEE
Type N<F,F,F>: 
  Mangled: 1NIJ1FS0_S0_EE
  Demangled: 1NIJ1FS0_S0_EE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersI1NIJ1FS1_S1_EEE
Type O<N,N>: 
  Mangled: 1OIJ1NS0_EE
  Demangled: 1OIJ1NS0_EE
  typeinfo<>: 19preserve_qualifiersI1OIJ1NS1_EEE
```

Does anyone have any idea how this might be resolved? Is it a bug in clang? (Or maybe a bug in GCC?) My first suspicion was a version incompatibility between the C++ ABI being linked with my code and the C++ ABI that clang is using. The fact that the issue only occurs with new C++11 features (member function ref-qualifiers and variadic templates) seems to support this suspicion... though r-value references (for example) don't have a problem.

In case it's relevant, I'm on Mac OSX Lion, and GCC 4.8 and clang 3.2 were installed from MacPorts. I'm using the following commands for compilation:

```
clang++-mp-3.2 -isystem/usr/local/include/c++/v1 -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 typeinfo-min.cpp -o typeinfofun-clang
G++-mp-4.8 -std=gnu++11 typeinfo-min.cpp -o typeinfofun-gcc
```

The isystem flag seems to be required in order to allow clang to find the libc++ headers (which was necessary when I was using `<type_traits>` for the more complicated version of this). Without it, it can't even find `<iostream>`.

(As an additional note, this issue does affect the more complicated version as well, since class names were — probably unsurprisingly — not among the specializations for complicated types, and thus just used the ABI demangle call.)

(Also as an aside, I'm curious about the portability of this. I know it's not necessary in MSVC since that returns the unmangled name from `typeid(...).name()`, but apart from that...)

Comment: Note: the top-level `const` qualifier of a parameter (as in `void foo(int const);` does not participate in the function signature (at all). Indeed, this function can be redeclared as `void foo(int);` without any conflict. It is therefore normal that it does not show up in the ABI. I am quite interested in the answers that will come up, especially with the ABI divergence between Clang and gcc, one is likely buggy.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. It seems a little odd that this would be the case though; why would void(void(*const)()) and void(void(*)()) be considered equivalent when (for example) void(int&) and void(const int&) are not? Or is the rule you mention universal after all but only for non-reference parameters, eg void(int) and void(const int) would be equivalent?

Comment: Because in `int const&` the `const` is not at the top level (it's nested within the reference, if you wish). However `int*` and `int* const` are similar *from the point of view of the caller*: any modification to the pointer value (not the pointee, the pointer) is not propagated back to the caller, so whether the implementation wishes it to be `const` or not is of no interest to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked on gcc4.8 mingw3.0 Your example:

> gcc version 4.8.1 20130324 (prerelease) (rubenvb-4.8-stdthread)

```
c++.exe -ggdb -Os -frtti -fexceptions -fpic -std=gnu++11
```

And I got that result

```
Type void(*volatile)(void(*const)()):
  Mangled: PFvPFvvEE
  Demangled: void (*)(void (*)())
  typeinfo<>: void (* volatile)(void (*)())
Type int (A::*)():
  Mangled: M1AFivE
  Demangled: int (A::*)()
  typeinfo<>: int (A::*)()
Type int (A::*)()const:
  Mangled: M1AKFivE
  Demangled: int (A::*)() const
  typeinfo<>: int (A::*)() const
Type int (A::*const)():
  Mangled: M1AFivE
  Demangled: int (A::*)()
  typeinfo<>: int (A::* const)()
Type F<int>:
  Mangled: 1FIiE
  Demangled: F<int>
  typeinfo<>: F<int>
Type G<3>:
  Mangled: 1GILi3EE
  Demangled: G<3>
  typeinfo<>: G<3>
Type H<F>:
  Mangled: 1HI1FE
  Demangled: H<F>
  typeinfo<>: H<F>
Type I<G>:
  Mangled: 1II1GE
  Demangled: I<G>
  typeinfo<>: I<G>
Type J<int>:
  Mangled: 1JIIiEE
  Demangled: J<int>
  typeinfo<>: J<int>
Type K<3>:
  Mangled: 1KIILi3EEE
  Demangled: K<3>
  typeinfo<>: K<3>
Type L<F>:
  Mangled: 1LII1FEE
  Demangled: L<F>
  typeinfo<>: L<F>
Type M<G>:
  Mangled: 1MII1GEE
  Demangled: M<G>
  typeinfo<>: M<G>
Type N<F,F,F>:
  Mangled: 1NII1FS0_S0_EE
  Demangled: N<F, F, F>
  typeinfo<>: N<F, F, F>
Type O<N,N>:
  Mangled: 1OII1NS0_EE
  Demangled: O<N, N>
  typeinfo<>: O<N, N>
```